# How to fire a Google Analytics event without impacting session count?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to prevent creating new session, while firing a Google Analytics event, when app is in Background (or killed state). Events like "PushNotificationReceived" need to be fired when app is not opened (or in background). But these events would increase session count.
Though it is possible to make user segment and filter out these sessions in Google Analytics Dashboard. But I'm looking for alternate way.
What should be the best approach to track these type of events without impacting session count or active users, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of Google Analytics events is that they supposed to be part of a session so there is no obvious way to set a tracking like that.